# html - css: line-height break flexing ability

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I have the following html structure for the top navigation bar.
I have a black line under the navigation which changes on hover. Im using scss and want my code to include flexboxes. I almost got to the desired result but i have one problem. when i resize the window the line for the right menu breaks - see picture attach.

[image: I suspect the line-height to] cause this problem but cant get over it. 
Thanks!

```css
.main-nav {
  margin-right: get-vw(260px);
  margin-left: get-vw(260px);
  font-weight: bold;
  flex: 3;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-family: var(--nav-font);
  background-color: var(--logo-bg-color);
  color: var(--logo-color);
  max-width: get-vw(980px);
  height: get-vw(124px);
  font-size: rem(40px); 
  // border-bottom: 6px solid transparent; 
}

.logo {
  background-color: var(--logo-bg-color);
  span {
    color: var(--logo-dot-color);
    font-size: rem(40px);
  }
}

.right-menu {
  display: flex;
  a {
    font-size: rem(16px);
    transition: color 0.5s;
  }
  li {    
    box-sizing: content-box;
    text-align: center;
    display: list-item;
    width: rem(130px);
    max-height: rem(124px);
    border-bottom: rem(6px) solid #1e1e1e;
    line-height: get-vw(130px);
    margin-right: rem(1px);
    margin-left: rem(1px);    
    background-color: var(--logo-bg-color);   
    }
  li:hover {
    color: var(--logo-dot-color);
    border-bottom: rem(6px) solid rgb(88, 202, 56);    
  }
}
   
.right-menu {
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <nav class="main-nav align-center">

      <ul class="clean-list logo">
        <li>
          <a>blogin<span>.</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="clean-list align-center right-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Journal</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jodos3vf/

Comment: maybe try adding "box-sizing: border-box" to your li elements https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Comment: Thanks LGSon i've edited my post - JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jodos3vf/